# CakePHP navigation bar logic

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

The navigation bar in my application will contain `User` information (name, profile pic), and some associated data. Since the navigation bar is going to be present in the whole application, I'm putting my logic inside `AppController::beforeRender()` in order to pass data to the `View` (in this case, the Element nav_bar).

1. Is this the right place to implement the logic to retrieve user information and associated data?.
2. Which of the followings is the correct way to load `User` model data.

   ```
   public function beforeRender() {
       $this->loadModel('User');  // this one
       $this->User->find(...                    

       ClassRegistry::init('User')->find(... // Or this one?
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would save the user information in a Session, otherwise you will be hitting the database in every single request.

So, what you wanna do is: in your login() function you get the user information and save it in a Session. Then, in your element, you simply echo the content you want from your Session.

Comment: It's a good idea but there's some additional data that may change while the user is logged,  if I store the data in the session, there is no way to know if the data has changed

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco you can change the Session whenever you want wherever you want.

Answer (score -1):

In your view, Use the AuthComponent class to access to the user information, for example :

to havethe id of user : `$use_id = AuthComponent::user('id');`

to have all the informations of user : `$user = AuthComponent::user();`

Comment: You don't use a component in a View, you are breaking the MVC principle